# Spring Integration Broadcasts of publish-subscribe-channel seams not to work when wiretapping

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, publish-subscribe, channel

I am getting message on a `int:publish-subscribe-channel` but only one of the subscribers will be called when wiretapping this channel (as it would be with a direct-channel). When I comment out the wiretap it works as expected. I am using `Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1`. Could also be reproduced with Spring Boot `1.5.10.RELEASE`.

The following configuration works as expected:

**Start-Code:**

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
PublishSubscribeChannel subscribeChannel = context.getBean("subscriber.channel", PublishSubscribeChannel.class);
subscribeChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test-String").build());
context.close();
```

**Configuration:**

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="subscriber.channel" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="subscriber.channel" level="WARN" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="subscriber.channel" level="ERROR" />
```

**Output:**

```
2018-02-07 16:08:51.308  WARN 11944 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Test-String
2018-02-07 16:08:51.315 ERROR 11944 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Test-String
```

When using channel interceptor the channel is not a Publish-Subscriber-Channel more but a direct-channel:

**Start-Code:**

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
PublishSubscribeChannel subscribeChannel = context.getBean("subscriber.channel", PublishSubscribeChannel.class);
subscribeChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test-String").build());
context.close();
```

**Configuration**

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="subscriber.channel" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="subscriber.channel" level="WARN" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="subscriber.channel" level="ERROR" />

<int:channel id="subscriber.channel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="incomeLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="incomeLogger" level="INFO" />
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" 2018-02-07 16:14:42.824  INFO 11928 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@667a738: startup date [Wed Feb 07 16:14:41 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'subscriber.channel' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:384)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1091)
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17)
```

When I change my Starter Code to:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
MessageChannel subscribeChannel = context.getBean("subscriber.channel", MessageChannel.class);
subscribeChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test-String").build());
context.close();
```

Then one "Subscriber" will be called and the channel is tracked by the interceptor:

```
2018-02-07 16:17:11.415  INFO 10040 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Test-String
2018-02-07 16:17:11.416  WARN 10040 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Test-String
```

**UPDATE:**

What also works is following configuration

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="subscriber.channel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="incomeLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:publish-subscribe-channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="incomeLogger" level="INFO" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="subscriber.channel" level="WARN" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="subscriber.channel" level="ERROR" />
```

**Output:**

```
2018-02-07 17:08:56.923  INFO 11300 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Test-String
2018-02-07 17:08:56.923  WARN 11300 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Test-String
2018-02-07 17:08:56.923 ERROR 11300 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Test-String
```

Is this expected or a bug? Or what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what you have:

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="subscriber.channel" />

<int:channel id="subscriber.channel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="incomeLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

Effectively you declare two beans, but both of them with the same `id`. So, only the second in definition order wins. But since it is a simple `channel` you definitely end up with the `DirectChannel` at runtime eliminating any possibility to appear of that `publish-subscribe-channel` result.

You should understand that XML configuration is parsed and the real object model in the end might be different.

So, your mistake that your override a target bean using the same `id`.

Your latest code with the `<int:interceptors>` for that `<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="subscriber.channel">` is correct. And I'm sure that latest logs are exactly what you would like to see.

Comment: Hi Artem, yes absolutely. I thought I could declare the wiretap while defining the channel I want to intercept. Randomly with direct-channel it worked (because I overwrote it with the same type of channel). With input of Joe we figured it out. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Hey Artem, just for my understanding. Why doesn't spring complain when having channel with same id multiple times? Shouldn't ids be unique?

Comment: It’s not about just channels , that’s applied to beans at all. Well, it complains: there should be some log message. And there is a flag on the `BeanFactory` to fail fast, but it’s false by default and not so easy to turn it on. Not sure though why it’s not true by default